# Java how to delay a program execution

Tags: java, wait

I have four web applications uses four different files to record logs. From my main application (log analyzer) I execute those four applications and then I'm going to read log files generated, but there is a lag (about 5sec and depends on machine execution speed) in between application execution and log generation.

What I want to do is some how wait the log analyzer execution till all these four log files are created and updated. Now I'm doing this by using

```
Thread.sleep(6000)
```

but this system fails on some environments which has low execution rate. I want to get an idea about how to implement a better solution for this by continuously checking whether the four files are created and content has been created.

Comment: i would suggest , read about observer pattern. its solve this kind of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting, you could use a [file system watcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to watch a directory and take action when a specific event has been fired.

This would allow your applications to not wait unnecessarily or else not to take action too early, which is what happens when you provide a fixed time period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this would be the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your log analyzer should wait for the log generation, not actively poll. Use [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html):

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If `t` is a `Thread` object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> ```
> t.join();
> ```
>
> causes the current thread to pause execution until `t`'s
>   thread terminates.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the 4 applications run independently of each other, and not as 4 threads.

Comment: Yes four applications run independently and those four applications are web applications running on a server.

Comment: I removed those tags.